# JPA: IN expression with many parameters

Tags: java, jpa, parameters

I have a JPA query with IN expression that applies a list of ID values. Usually the size of a list is is huge (~2000 items). This list is returned from another JPA query as a result of complex calculations and I don't want to fetch the same data in in a sub-query one more time.

```
SELECT e.name FROM Employee e WHERE e.id IN (:employeeIdList)
```

The problem is that the performance of such queries is very bad when they are translated to  native SQL. Is there a proper way to pass a huge set of values into a query without affecting the performance that mush?

I'd like to get rid of the IN expression if possible. I've looked into docs on JPA, it seems it doesn't support temporary tables, or maybe I'm missing something.